# PHP / AJAX Shopping cart not working correctly

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm having some problems with, building a shopping cart.

I cannot set a different quantity for each items in my shop. The quantity should be picked up from an input field, at that is working fine. But if you're setting the quantity to 3 for item 1, and the quantity to 5 for item 2, every items will have the quantity of 5 (the last added).

Also when you're trying to delete one of the items, the quantity now will be set to zero, of every items. It is like, that the quantity of each item is not stored, and I have no idea why this is happening.

The cart I'm using, is PHP/SQL and AJAX.

This is my code so far:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// This doument contains the AJAX generated for the building-cart
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Clear Cache and include config.php
include("includes/config.php");
// Start Session
session_start();

?>
<?php

$product_id = $_GET['id']; //the product id from the URL 
$action = $_GET['action']; //the action from the URL
$quantitys = $_GET['qun']; //the action from the URL 

// if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error message
if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
}

// decide what to do 
switch($action) {

    case "add":

    //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
    if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] < 1) { $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; }

    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
    break;

}
?>
<?php 

//if the cart isn't empty show the cart
if($_SESSION['cart']) {

    echo '<ul id="cart-items">'."\n";

    //iterate through the cart, the $product_id is the key and $quantity is the value
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantityt) { 

        //get the name, description and price from the database - this will depend on your database implementation.
        //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM single_partners WHERE single_id = $product_id");

        //Only display the row if there is a product (though there should always be as we have already checked)
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            if($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $partner_id = $test['partner_id'];
                $partner_price = $test['price'];
            }   

            // Get partner name
            $get_partner_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partners WHERE partner_id='$partner_id'");
            if($partner_name = mysql_fetch_array($get_partner_name)) {

                $name = $partner_name['name'];
                $logo = $partner_name['logo'];
                $type = $partner_name['type'];
                $logo_dir = "media/partners/build/color/";

                $line_cost = $partner_price * $quantitys; //work out the line cost
                $total = $total + $line_cost; //add to the total cost
            }

            echo '<li>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="logo" style="background-image: url('.$logo_dir.$logo.')">'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="details">'."\n";
            echo '<span class="name">'.$name.'</span>'."\n";
            echo '<span class="details">details</span>'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '<div class="price"><input name="qun" type="hidden" value="'.$quantitys.'" /><input name="partner" type="hidden" value="'.$product_id.'" /><span class="remove-button"></span>'."\n";
            echo '<span class="price">'.number_format((float)$line_cost, 2, ',', '').'</span>'."\n";
            echo '</div>'."\n";
            echo '</li>'."\n";
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="footer">'."\n";
    echo '<span class="empty-button">Empty</span>'."\n";
    echo '<span class="total-price">'.number_format((float)$total, 2, ',', '').'</span>'."\n";
    echo '</div>'."\n";
    echo '</ul>'."\n";



}else{
//otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
    //echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";

}

//function to check if a product exists
function productExists($product_id) {
    //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM single_partners WHERE single_id = $product_id");

    return mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0;
}
?>
```

**AJAX Call:**

```
// Load building cart, when adding items
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=button].add-button', function() {

    // AJAX - Define data to send
    var actiontype = "add";
        productid = $('input[name="address"]').val();
        quantity = $('input[name="qun"]').val();
    var data = "action="+ actiontype + "&id="+ productid + "&quantity="+ quantity;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buildingcart.php',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {  
            // Show result
            $('#building-cart .content').html(result);
        }
    });
});

// Load building cart, when adding items
$(document).on('click', '.remove-button', function() {

    // AJAX - Define data to send
    var actiontype = "remove";
        productid = $(this).parent().find('input[name="partner"]').val();

    var data = "action="+ actiontype + "&id="+ productid;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buildingcart.php',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {  
            // Show result
            $('#building-cart .content').html(result);
        }
    });
});

// Load building cart, when adding items
$(document).on('click', '.empty-button', function() {

    // AJAX - Define data to send
    var actiontype = "empty";

    var data = "action="+ actiontype;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'buildingcart.php',
        data: data,
        success:function(result) {  
            // Show result
            $('#building-cart .content').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried changing

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity)
```

to

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id)
```

with no luck.

I also want to have the ability to set a different size for each item, but the same thing happens here. It always takes the quantity/size of the last added item, and update it to the rest of the items, which is not intended.

Sorry for the long codes.. Hope someone can help me :-)

Comment: your `foreach` uses `$quantitys` but when you remove item you are not passing `$quantitys` so it will be null. and results in 0